# Does the inverse command of cut exist?

Tags: text-processing, cut

I like using the `cut` command in Linux with the `-c` flag. However, I'm interested in finding a command that sort of does the set inverse of `cut`. Essentially, given the input:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 4096 4 20:15 bin
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 4096 4 20:15 Desktop
```

I would like to see everything *except* “4096 4 20:15”. Here is the output:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root bin
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root Desktop
```

I want to be able to literally cut out between characters x and y, if that makes sense.

Any ideas? I can't imagine it'd be a hard script to write but if there already exists a command for it, I'd love to use it.

Comment: That's also `cut`: `cut -c -23,42-`. But actually this is the worst possible idea. See [Why you shouldn't parse the output of ls(1)](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for explanation.

Comment: Is there `stat` on your system? (Usually is on Linux, its a GNU tool.) `stat -c '%A %h %U %G %n' *`

Comment: The corresponding command to `cut` is [`paste`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/paste.html), although I see that your question needs just another incantation of `cut` (as already answered).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As others have pointed out, [you should not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Assuming you are using `ls` only as an example and will be parsing something else, there are a few ways of doing what you want:

1. `cut` with  `-d` and `-f`

   ```
   cut -d ' ' -f 1,2,3,4,9
   ```

   from `man cut`:

   ```
   -d, --delimiter=DELIM
         use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter

   -f, --fields=LIST
         select only these fields;  also print any line
         that contains no delimiter  character,  unless
         the -s option is specified
   ```

   Specifically for `ls` this is likely to fail since `ls` will change the amount of whitespace between consecutive fields to make them align better. `cut` treats `foo<space>bar` and `foo<space><space>bar` differently.
2. `awk` and its variants split each input line into fields on white space so you can tell it to print only the fields you want:

   ```
   awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$9}'
   ```
3. Perl

   ```
   perl -lane 'print "@F[0 .. 3,8]"'
   ```

Comment: @manatwork I edited my answer, is that what you meant? However, it does work quite often, I tested it in a simple directory and since the alignment was fine, `cut` worked as expected.

Comment: `awk` for `$9` and `perl` for `$F[8]` will output only the first words of the file names. The later is easy to correct with `print "@F[0 .. 3,8 .. $#F]"`.

Comment: @manatwork please note that I am not using `ls` for any of my suggestions for exactly that reason. These will all break for weird file names, spaces and new lines and carriage returns oh my!

Comment: Yes, I observed the removal of `ls` but was not sure whether was only to shorten the examples or not.

Comment: @manatwork no, it was to make it clear that I am not suggesting parsing ls. For all the reasons you pointed out.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the inverse of the results of `cut` by using the `--complement` option. The `cut` [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html) says (somewhat unhelpfully):

> --complement
>
> ```
>           complement the set of selected bytes, characters or fields
> ```

So, for instance,

`$ echo The fifth and sixth words will be missing | cut -d ' ' -f 5-6 --complement
The fifth and sixth be missing`

Explanation:

- `-d ' '` sets the delimiter to the space character
- `-f 5-6` selects the fields 5 through 6 ("words will") to be output
- `--complement` returns the complement (inverse) of the selected text

Answer (score 0):

Using `stat` to replace `ls` isn't a drop-in replacement, so for all the well-intentioned admonishment against parsing `ls`, I can appreciate the seduction...

Here's an almost equivalent of of an `ls -a` in the current dir:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -print0|xargs -0 stat --format="%A %U %G %n"
```

Here's the nearest I could get it:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -print0\
|awk 'BEGIN{RS="\0";FS="/";ORS="\0"}{if(/\//){print $2}else{print}}'\
|xargs -0 stat --format="%A %U %G %n"\
|LC_COLLATE=C sort -k4
```

Now, to take an argument instead of just `.`, you'd want to put it into a function kinda like this:

```
function ls4up() {
    find . -maxdepth 1 -print0\
    |awk 'BEGIN{RS="\0";FS="/";ORS="\0"}{if(/^[^\/][^\/]*\//){print $2}else{print}}'\
    |xargs -0 stat --format="%A %U %G %n"\
    |LC_COLLATE=C sort -k4 
}
```

So now you see how easy it is to use `stat` instead of trying to parse the output of `ls` or something. /s