# How to remove a column or multiple columns from file using shell command?

Tags: shell, shell-script, text-processing, sed, awk

Input:

```
ARCHIVE  B1_NAME  B2_NAME  B3_NAME  ELEMENT  INFO_NAM WERT PROCID
-------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- ---- ------
15MinAvg AIRSS    33-GIS   DMDMGIS1 I        MvAvr15m 1123  CP
15MinAvg AIRSS    33-GIS   DMDMGIS1 P        MvAvr15m 2344  CP
15MinAvg AIRSS    33-GIS   DMDMGIS1 Q        MvAvr15m 4545  CP
15MinAvg AIRSS    33-GIS   DMDMGIS2 I        MvAvr15m 6576  CP
15MinAvg AIRSS    33-GIS   DMDMGIS2 P        MvAvr15m 4355  CP
15MinAvg AIRSS    33-GIS   DMDMGIS2 Q        MvAvr15m 6664  CP
```

Output:

```
ARCHIVE  B1_NAME  B2_NAME  B3_NAME  ELEMENT WERT
-------- -------- -------- -------- ------- ----
15MinAvg AIRSS    33-GIS   DMDMGIS1 I       1123
15MinAvg AIRSS    33-GIS   DMDMGIS1 P       2344
15MinAvg AIRSS    33-GIS   DMDMGIS1 Q       4545
15MinAvg AIRSS    33-GIS   DMDMGIS2 I       6576
15MinAvg AIRSS    33-GIS   DMDMGIS2 P       4355
15MinAvg AIRSS    33-GIS   DMDMGIS2 Q       6664
```

I want to delete the two columns `INFO_NAM` and `PROCID` from my input file.

Comment: Which two columns do you really want to be removed. Your output has `INFO_NAM` & `PROCID` deleted

Comment: `awk '{$(NF-1)=$(NF-2)=""};1' <file | column -t` can format it nicely.

Comment: Related: "Does the inverse of `cut` exist?" https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/89869/323093

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This has been answered before elsewhere on Stack Overflow:

- [delete a column with awk or sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361632/delete-a-column-with-awk-or-sed)
- [Deleting columns from a file with awk or from command line on linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551219/deleting-columns-from-a-file-with-awk-or-from-command-line-on-linux)

  etc..

I believe `awk` is the best for that.

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$7}' file
```

It is possible to use `cut` as well.

```
cut -f1,2,3,4,5,7 file
```

Comment: just to mention it: the `--complement` option for `cut` might be handy in here, i.e. removing two fields rather than selecting six: `cut -f6,8 --complement file`

Comment: awk is working...... but whats happening... the format is changed.... its just taking the field but not the exact structure... and      cut is not working... @AndreiR

Comment: I have tried this, `cut –c1-45,55-58`. But before executing this I have to count the total characters then only I can us this. But I wanted to print the columns with the same as my input format

Comment: @Nainita maybe you have different separator that is not space. In awk you should specify it (i.e. using -F "\t" if tabular). Using cut, it is necessary to use -d (cut -d, if using comma).

Comment: @AndreiR `cut -f1 file` doesn't work. see [this image](https://imgur.com/a/J2XEk)

Comment: @alhelal can you try cut -f 1 -d ' ' ?

Comment: fyi. the `cut`-based answere below (and here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/615758/36362) works for me, on macOS 10.14.6 anyway.

Answer (score 52):

If you are content to clear the columns rather than completely removing them:

Don't print 6<sup>th</sup> and 8<sup>th</sup> column

```
awk '{$6=$8=""; print $0}' file
```

Comment: This doesn't work in cases where the delimiter is something besides space; it makes the contents of the field the empty string, but does not remove the field altogether.  See `echo "a|b|c|d|e" | awk -v FS='|' -v OFS='|' '{$2=$4=""; print}'` yields `a||c||e`

Answer (score 16):

The best way to delete columns is with `cut`:

```
cut --complement -d' ' -f6,8 file
```

Explanation:

- `-d` specifies the delimiter; in this case, a space
- `--complement` keeps the columns other than the ones specified in `-f`
- `-f` specifies the columns to cut (rather than the columns to keep, since `--complement` is being used); in this case, columns 6 and 8

From the [cut man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1.html):

> ```
>   -d, --delimiter=DELIM
>         use DELIM instead of TAB for field delimiter
>
>   -f, --fields=LIST
>          select only these fields;  also print any line that contains
>          no delimiter character, unless the -s option is specified
>
>   --complement
>          complement the set of selected bytes, characters or fields
> ```

Some others have proposed using a construction like `awk '{$2=$4=""; print $0}'`, but this doesn't work in cases where the delimiter is something besides space; it makes the contents of the field the empty string, but does not remove the field altogether. For example, `echo "a|b|c|d|e" | awk -v FS='|' -v OFS='|' '{$2=$4=""; print}'` yields `a||c||e`.

Comment: MacOS aka BSD doesn't seem to have `--compliement`

Comment: @Rick see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45851402/cut-command-in-mac-terminal-lacks-complement-option for workaround using `brew install coreutils` and `gcut` in terminal.

Comment: Ok thanks I will take a look

Comment: Works for me on macOS 10.14.6 with homebrew `coreutils`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `printf` to preserve the format of each field. Each field is x characters long and the minus sign justifies the string left.

```
awk '{ printf("%-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-4s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $7)}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to a Perl solution...

```
perl -ane 'printf("%-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-8s %-4s\n", $F[0], $F[1], $F[2], $F[3], $F[4], $F[6])' file
```

These command-line options are used:

- `-n` loop around every line of the input file, do not automatically print every line
- `-a` autosplit mode – split input lines into the @F array.  Defaults to splitting on whitespace
- `-e` execute the following perl code